# Is it possible to split DNS depending on area of originating traffic?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, sharepoint

I have two SharePoint server farms that are in two different subnets. I have noticed that all of the servers in each of these farms are configured with the same DNS servers.

My goal is to be able to have the same SharePoint URL's in both farms which sounds impossible since they are using the same DNS servers.

Is it possible to do some kind of split depending on subnet of originating traffic?

Example: someone trying to access teams.sharepoint.mydomain.com goes to Farm 1 if their IP is 10.1.1.* but if their IP is 10.2.1.* and they attempt to go to the *same URL* they go to Farm 2

Is this possible at all?

Thank you

Comment: It's trivial to accomplish with BIND.  The relevant feature is called "views."  No idea how to do it with the windows DNS server though.

Comment: `I have noticed that all of the servers in each of these farms are configured with the same DNS servers.` It doesn't particularly matter which DNS servers a given server has configured for itself, but rather what DNS servers the *clients* have configured. Either way, you're looking at BIND views or some sort of load-balancing (with layer-7 abilities) to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of dns server.

It is supported in bind (the linux most-used dns server) and it's called "views"

It's not supported on Windows 2008 DNS server. But the feature "netmask ordering" may do the trick.

I'm unsure for windows 2012 DNS server.